# how to access array position?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have this content being returned. How can I access data inside 0?

I've tried date[0] but it didn't work

```
const { data } = getData();
```

console.log(data) result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTIYt.png)

Comment: Try data[0] instead of date[0]. This should give you an object. You can access its properties like data[0].id & so on.

Answer (score 1):

In the image that you've posted it indicates that `data` is an array of objects, so you can access it by doing:

```js
console.log(data[0]);
console.log(data[1]);
// and so on..
```

If you want to access some specific property inside of an object, you can do it by doing this:

```js
console.log(data[0].id);
```

Comment: dont work, i try

Comment: Can you please post what is the error you are getting, so I can update my answer?

Comment: error: unhandled runtime error

typeError: data is undefined

Comment: Okay, that means that you are not able to access `data`. Can you update your question with full code snippet, so I can see why `data` is not there?

Thanks!

Comment: @BryanLima. that makes no sense. You can clearly log `data` as you've shown in your question. Logging `data[0]` shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply specify the index of the array?

```js
const { data } = getData();
console.log(data[0])

function getData() {
  return {
    data: [{
      name: "Test 1"
    },
    {
      name: "Test 2"
    }]
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** *The data returned is a sample*